# In magento 2 How to show all customer review in separate custom page?

Tags: magento2, customer, review

In magento2,using custom modules i need to show customer review in separate page like

- reviewer name,
- rating given
- Which Product customer gave rating? etc.

Let me know how to get all those details in custom page.

Answer (score 0):

You have call review collection class `\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory` at your custom page's block class.

Inject this class at __construct().

**Block Class**

```
/**
 * Product reviews collection
 *
 * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\Collection
 */
protected $_collection;

/**
 * Review resource model
 *
 * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
.....
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
.................
) {
.......
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
.......

}
/**
 * Get reviews
 *
 * @return bool|\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\Collection
 */
public function getReviews()
{

    if (!$this->_collection) {
        $this->_collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $this->_collection
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->setDateOrder();
        $this->_collection->addReviewSummary()
    }
    return $this->_collection;
}
```